# Accumulation point of zeros of a continuous function with a certain limit at boundary!

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{D}$ which is not continuous on $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$. Furthermore, assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\rightarrow 1}|f(z)|=b$ where $b\neq0$.  Let $Z=\{z_k\}\subset\mathbb{D}$  be the zero set of $f$. Can $Z$ have an accumulation point $z \in \partial \mathbb{D}$?

If $f$ is continuous on  $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$, the answer is negative because $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} f(z_k)=f(\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} z_k)=f(z)=0$ which contradicts the assumption $\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\rightarrow 1}|f(z)|=b$, $b\neq0$. But, I don't know what we can say when $f$ is not continuous on  $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same method you have already used. If $Z$ has an accumulation point on the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$ then there is a sequence $\{z_k\}\subset Z$ converging to a point on the boundary, say $z$. Then,
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} |f(z_k)|= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} 0=0$$
But this contradicts the hypothesis. To see why this is a contradiction recall what does it mean to say that $\lim_{|z|\rightarrow 1}|f(z)|=b$.